# SQL Server Express 2019 automatic backup activity

Tags: sql-server, backup

[image]

The activity shown in the image occurs every six hours. I have no external backup software running. Is there a way to configure SQL Server to not do this as often? The database is used very little and backups every six hours are not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

> The activity shown in the image occurs every six hours. I have no external backup software running.

Something is running and it is being invoked via VSS. So, yes, there is definitely something running inside or outside the environment.

> Is there a way to configure SQL Server to not do this as often?

It isn't SQL doing this, it's being invoked from outside of SQL Server.